# Google Play Account Deletion Requirement

Tags: android, google-play-console

My app allows users to create accounts. I noticed in the Google Play console a message that I should provide the ability of account deletion.  I have this functionality in my mobile app in the account section (the user should be logged in to delete his account obviously ).  But the message says there should be a web URL with the same feature.

If your app allows users to create an account from within your app, then it must also allow users to request for their account to be deleted. Users must have a readily discoverable option to initiate app account deletion from within your app and outside of your app (for example, by visiting your website). A link to this web resource must be entered in the designated URL form field within Play Console.

I don't understand clearly how it should be: just a link to the profile page with the delete account button, like it is in the mobile app, or some kind of form where the user may apply the deletion request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It says that you should also provide a "Delete account" functionality on the website, where user can delete the account.

Well, it can be possible in both ways. You either make it possible only for logged in users or directly just by entering the email or username or whatever credentials are needed for you to get the unique user account.

So, user can request their account to be deleted without logging in - I think this might be the right way to "Account deletion feature".

If user deletes his account from the app, then it's alright, but you should also provide the other option as well that I mentioned above because, what if user has forgotten the password and instead of creating a new password for continue using the app, he just wants to delete the account with just a username or email.

So, give it a try and it must work if done correctly.

Comment: what if someone else wants to delete my account using this way? how should we allow someone to delete other's account by just knowing their username or email

Comment: @jamal, you should send a confirmation link to user's email

Comment: what about if I provide a link telling the user that should contact the support and I provide the email support to contact for deleting the account, it's enough? or should I provide a way to write their email for deletion?

Comment: what if I am using a phone number? @amin-memariani

Comment: I don't think Google would accept that link. The authority should be given to the users themselves to delete their accounts. You can SMS a link to confirm the account deletion if you use the phone number.

Comment: I'm using social login so there is no need to a password, how I can deal with that

Comment: If you use social login, then you need to keep the basic reference info for that account. For example, you can take basic details from the social info and add some generated key to it and use that as the main credential to identify the user (Only for you, background process). Maybe then, you'll be able to differentiate each user and proceed further.

Comment: What can I do if my app is available only in android/iOS, no website? Please, please advise

Comment: You can add account deletion functionality in the app. If you're using a login module, then there must be a way to access that information, right? You can then implement a functionality that deletes the account information upon user confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue recently so I'll give you my knowledge about this issue.

First of all since you have already added the feature to delete account from your app so you are the half way to go. in case you use social login if you store these data in any database so you have the same issue so make sure to delete it as well

Plus it's recommended to refer to a deletion link for the user to delete its account. You can play around this part by making a google form associated to your developer account so the user can fill the form and you will get notified about it. Providing the form link will make your app appear in the play store as: **The developer provides a way for you to request that your data be deleted**.

Comment: Could you please share a sample of the google form you created. or a sample of it? and where have you placed in the website/app

Answer (score -2):

If your app allows users to create an account from within your app, then it must also allow users to request for their account to be deleted. **Users must have a readily discoverable option to initiate app account deletion from within your app and outside of your app (for example, by visiting your website)**. A link to this web resource must be entered in the designated URL form field within Play Console.
Refer:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10144311?visit_id=638071488555400797-3932952839&rd=1&hl=en